# Typescript apply arithmetic operation to each object's key of type number

Tags: typescript, types, generic-programming

I was wondering if there is some kind of generic solution in typescript for applying a arithmetic operation on each key of a object:

For example if I would like to multiply every key of an object with 3, I would expect the following.
(It would be even better if the function would apply the arithmetic operation only to keys of type number, but that's not a must have)

```
type type1 = {
  key1: number;
};

type type2 = {
  key2: number;
  key3: number;
};

let obj1: type1 = {
  key1: 1,
};

let obj2: type2 = {
  key2: 2,
  key3: 3,
};

genericFunc(obj1);
genericFunc(obj2);

// Expected result:
// obj1 = {
//   key1: 3,
// };

// obj2 = {
//   key2: 6,
//   key3: 9,
// };
```

Answer (score 0):

Expressing this in the type system is possible, but actually implementing the function requires some `<any>` casts I think.  It's possible someone is cleverer than me, and can figure out how to write the function without these unsafe casts.

From the type system's perspective, I break this into three steps:

- A clever mapping of the types properties
- Collapsing the type into a union
- Picking the subset of the type that appears in the union

That looks like so (genericised to more than just `number`).

```js
// each member becomes either "member": "member", or "member": never
type AllowedProperties<TBase, TAllowed> = {
  [K in keyof TBase]: TBase[K] extends TAllowed ? K : never
};

// now union all properties together, the nevers will be removed
type AllowedNames<TBase, TAllowed> =
  AllowedProperties<TBase, TAllowed>[keyof TBase];

// makes a new type where the members that are in AllowedName are selected
//   from TObject
//
// Note that Pick<T, U> is a built in helper type
type JustPropertiesOf<TObject, TOf> = 
  Pick<TObject, AllowedNames<TObject, TOf>>;
```

As a concrete example, we can define a new type and see what each of these types does to it:

```js
type Varied = {
  key1: number,
  key2: string,
  key3: object,
  key4: number
}

/*
type VariedProps = {
    key1: "key1";
    key2: never;
    key3: never;
}
*/
type VariedProps = AllowedProperties<Varied , number>;

/*
type VariedNames = "key1" | "key4"
*/ 
type VariedNames = AllowedNames<Varied, number>;

type VariedNumbers = {
    key1: number;
    key4: number;
}
/*
type VariedNumbers = JustPropertiesOf<Varied, number>;
```

Actually *using* the types is tricky.  I resorted to some `<any>`, so you could have nice typing *outside* of the function but you'd have to be sure of the implementation.  The fundamental issue is that you can't really create an object that conforms to `JustPropertiesOf<T,V>`, nor assert that keys to assign to it are in `AllowedNames<T,V>`.

What I did was this:

```js
function genericOverNumbers<TObject>(
  plainObject: TObject,
  del: (a: number) => number): JustPropertiesOf<TObject, number>
{
  let ret: any = {};
  for (const key in plainObject) {
    const val = plainObject[key];
    if (typeof val == "number") {
      const knownKey = <any>key;

      const mapped = del(val);
      ret[knownKey] = mapped;
    }
  }

  return ret;
}
```

A more generic function (one that has a `TOf` in place of `number`) is also tricky, since the `typeof val` guard only works for some constrained types.  I'd probably take a type guard function as a parameter, but that'd introduce some additional unsafety (since you'd need to type val as `any` too).